# how parse Local XML file in Titanium?

Tags: xml-parsing, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I would like to know how to parse XML file from local in Titanium App?

```
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile("Translation1.xml");
if ( file.exists() ) {
Ti.API.info("found");
 var xmltext = file.read().text;
    var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext); 
 //   var books = xmlMessage.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DUAS");
   //  Ti.API.info(xmltext.length); //Returns 50
     Ti.API.info(xmltext);      //Returns [Ti.Document  
 }
else
{
Ti.API.info("not found");
 }

}
catch(e)
{
 alert(e); 
 Ti.API.info(e);

}
```

i get only first line of the file, like following

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

how can i get all the data from that xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by reading the ['Working with XML Data'](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+XML+Data) guide.

Answer (score 0):

After you have parse the string, you have to search the elements too:

```
var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext);
var results = doc.getElementsByTagName('yourxmltag');
```

Now you can loop for each of the element found:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    arr[i] = results.item(i).text;
}
```

Now `arr` array has your results.